# Как правильно указать Docker на статические файлы?

Tags: python, docker

В Docker новичок, пытаюсь разместить Django проект на Docker, но он категорически отказывается видеть статические файлы, подскажите что не так? 
При запуске на ПК через manage.py runserver таких проблем нет.
https://github.com/WettoZ/hemming

Возможно ли это сделать без docker-compose.yml?

Вторая папка static в директории hem лишняя, запихнул туда вовремя тестов. Основная hem/apps/project/static

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чём сложности со сборкой текущего проекта?

Comment: Проект собирается и работает, но не видит css файл. Получается голый html

Comment: Без докера такая проблема есть?

Comment: Нет.  manage.py runserver работает превосходно

Comment: Так вы же запускаете проект из докера, а путь у вас остался как в локалмашине

Comment: Путь по отношению к setting.py же не изменился, какие изменения я должен внести?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что не собираются статические файлы (а именно нужно выполнить команду `manage.py collectstatic`). `runserver` делает это автоматически если `DEBUG==True`, а при запуске в gunicorn нужно это делать самому.

Добавьте команду ближе к концу Dockerfile-а:

```
RUN python manage.py collectstatic
```